# How to have a Bootstrap navbar item not collapse into the hamburger icon when on mobile view, but instead sit to the left of it?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y7ktfr0x/)

I am trying to prevent the right navbar item titled `Settings` in the jsfiddle example to not collapse with the rest of the navbar items into the hamburger icon when in mobile view, but instead sit to the left of the hamburger icon. Can this be achieved without having duplicate `Settings` dropdowns for each view, and if so, how?

```
<div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Settings <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would accomplish this by hiding the Settings dropdown that resides in your `navbar-collapse` element when in mobile view by using `hidden-xs` like so:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right hidden-xs">
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Settings <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and displaying a separate Settings dropdown next to your `button` element *only* in mobile view by using `visible-xs` like so:

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>

<ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right visible-xs">
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Settings <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I updated your Fiddle to give a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/y7ktfr0x/10/

---

### UPDATE

If you wanted to accomplish this without having two separate Settings dropdowns, you can just have one outside of your `navbar-collapse` element and apply some styling to it to keep it on the right side of the navbar like so:

```
<div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 0px;">
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Settings <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Updated Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/y7ktfr0x/17/

The only problem with this approach, as you can see in the Fiddle, is that you'll have to throw a media query into your CSS to make sure the absolute positioning of the dropdown goes to it's proper position to the left of the hamburger button when in mobile view.

Comment: I updated my question. Can this be achieved without having a dropdown for each view?

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: After adding in the media queries, you can see the drop downs behave unexpectedly. https://jsfiddle.net/y7ktfr0x/18/

Comment: Yep, you'll have to do a lot of fiddling around with the CSS to get it the way you want it. As I mentioned, this approach is not ideal at all. Although my first solution is not the ["DRYest"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) approach, it's really going to be your best bet if you're wanting to use the out-of-the-box functionality of Bootstrap without having to pull your hair out overriding a *bunch* of CSS. Even though you'll have two potentially identical Settings dropdowns, it will otherwise fit into the default constraints of Bootstrap without any ugly hacking.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you meant?

https://jsfiddle.net/y7ktfr0x/11/

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown pull-right">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Settings <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: For the mobile view yes, but otherwise I need the item on the right of the navbar.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this but it takes a whole lot of hacking to get it done. This is just an example so you'll have to adjust it to suit your needs or to correct any inconsistencies as far as positioning goes but it should get you started I believe.

See example Snippet at FullPage and Reduce the browser.

```css
.navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-navbar {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -45px;
  float: right;
}
.navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-navbar .nav.nav-right > li > a {
  color: #777;
  background: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-navbar .nav.nav-right > li > a:hover,
.navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-navbar .nav.nav-right > li > a:focus {
  color: white;
}
.navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-navbar .nav.nav-right li.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  text-align: right;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle {
    margin-right: 110px;
    border: none;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-navbar .nav.nav-right li.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
    margin-right: -10px;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-navbar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    right: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>

    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-navbar">
      <ul class="nav nav-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Settings <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>
```